# Lotus Notes Java replication of remote database

Tags: java, replication, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a lot of Lotus Notes / Domino (version 7) database to migrate to a new software.
On my workstation (with Lotus Notes installed), I'm using a standalone Java application to connect to a local replica an extract data. 
However the replication of the distant database is still a manual process. I'd like to automatise it.

My java code basically looks like this :

```
Session localSession = NotesFactory.createSession(); // With Notes thread initialized
Session remoteSession = NotesFactory.createSession(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);

Database localDb = localSession.getDbDirectory(null).openDatabase("local_name", true);
Database remoteDb = remoteSession.getDbDirectory(null).openDatabaseByReplicaID(REPLICA);

//    ***EDITED CALLING INSTANCE BELOW***
remoteDb.createReplica(null, "local_name"); // Error thrown here
```

However the last line throws an exception (from memroy, but something like)

```
CN=****/***** does not have the right to create database on a server
```

How is it possible that I don't have the right to create database on my local computer ?

Is there any other way to programmaticly create a local replica from a distant database ?

Edit: changed calling instance of create replica to match my code causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it looks like I found the answer.

AFAIU I had to open the database on the target server, using my local session, and run the createReplica() from here. This way, the createReplica is executed on my local Lotus Notes server, and the replica is created locally.

```
Session     localSession        = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, PASSWORD);
DbDirectory remoteDbDirectory   = localSession.getDbDirectory(remoteSession.getServerName());           
Database    localSessionRemoteDatabase = remoteDbDirectory.openDatabaseByReplicaID(REMOTE_REPLICA_ID);          
localSessionRemoteDatabase.createReplica("", LOCAL_FILE_NAME);
```

@Richard Schwartz Can you confirm this is ok ?

The only weird thing, is that it opens a prompt (like when it's expecting password) but the replica is created.
The process is executed within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's just giving you the wrong error message. One thing that's definitely wrong is that he first argument for createReplica should be an empty string, not a null pointer. I.e., try this:

```
localDb.createReplica("", "local_name");
```

Comment: I edited my post. I'm calling the create replica on the remote database. I think this is the issue. I'm confused: what is the process for creating a local replica of a remote database from scratch using Java ? Thanks

Comment: Oh, wait a minute... Are you using NCSO.jar, instead of notes.jar? If that's the case, you have no "Local". Your API calls are all executing on the server.

Comment: But also, again, in your revised code you should not be passing null as the first argument to createReplica(). It should be an empty string, "", not a null pointer to string.

Comment: No I'm definitely running using Notes.jar on my local computer. The Notes.jar is taken from the Lotus Notes installation directory.
But calling remoteDb.createReplica("", "local_name") will create a replica on the server or on my computer ?

Comment: If you're using notes.jar, then calling remoteDb.createReplica("", "local_name") will create a local replica on your computer.

Comment: But hmm... Why do you have two sessions? You only need one. A Notes session is not tied to a server. And the call that you are making to NotesFactory.createSession in order to open the remoteSession is passing in the user and password arguments. You don't need that if you're using notes.jar. You use that version of createSession() when you want to use IIOP to run your methods on the server. When using notes.jar, the user argument is null. You don't need it, because the user info comes from the id file in your Notes installation.

Comment: I think that's what's happening to you. Maybe the IIOP-based methods also exist in notes.jar, although I never thought they did. Get rid of remoteSession. Access everything, local and remote, through a single session that is opened the way you open your localSession.